# Get the IDs of all objects in a list

Tags: grails

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo {
    String bar
}
```

I am trying to get the IDs of all the `Foo` objects whose `bar` String is in the list `bars`.  I have tried it several ways, always receiving the same error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Collection
```

Some of the things I have tried:

```
def ids = Foo.findAllByBarInList( bars )*.id
def ids = Foo.findAllByBarInList( bars ).collect{ it.id }
def ids = Foo.findAllByBarInList( bars ).collect{ it -> it?.id }
```

**UPDATE:**

I was making `bars` with [split](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#split%28%29) so it was an array, not a list. It threw me off because `Foo.findAllByBarInList( bars )` returned my `Foo` objects just fine, only when I tried to collect the ids did it fail.  I now make `bars` with [tokenize](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#tokenize%28%29) instead and all is well.

Comment: I added the groovy tag back to this question because both the `collect` method and the spread operator `*.` are based in groovy.

Comment: Are you sure the list you are checking against is set up correctly as a list?  Using `def ids = Foo.findAllByBarInList( bars )*.id` works for me.

Comment: I'd leave the Groovy tag off since Grails uses Groovy, so it's not necessary, and it's just the usage of Groovy within Grails, not a Groovy-specific question. A Groovy expert who has no experience with Grails wouldn't be able to help you. Similarly you can omit the Java, GORM, Hibernate, Spring, Programming tags ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That works for me as long as `bars` is a List

```
def bars = ['bar1', 'bar3']
def ids = Foo.findAllByBarInList(bars)*.id
```

But if all you want is the `id` field it's a waste to pull entire domain class instances from the database. For now there's just the one field, but in practice it will likely be a larger table. So I'd use an HQL query:

```
def ids = Foo.executeQuery(
   'select f.id from Foo f where f.bar in (:bars)',
   [bars: bars])
```